# Python encoding problems: zip csv buffers (Django)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, csv

In a Django view, I want to create some csv files in memory, and zip them to download.

I'm using Django 1.11 / Python 2.7. My code:

```
import csv
import zipfile
import StringIO


files = []

csv_buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(csv_buffer)
writer.writerow(["val1", "str1"])

csv_buffer.seek(0)

files.append(csv_buffer)

zipped_file = StringIO.StringIO()

with zipfile.ZipFile(zipped_file, 'w') as zipper:
    for i, file in enumerate(files):
        file.seek(0)
        zipper.writestr("{}.csv".format(i), file.read())

zipped_file.seek(0)

# response = HttpResponse(csv_buffer, content_type='text/csv')
# response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=results.csv'
response = HttpResponse(zipped_file, content_type='application/zip')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=results.zip'
return response
```

With this code, the csv is encoded utf-8 but my editor complains about 'invalid characters'.

If I just return the csv file, I get an empty csv. No idea why..

I think the StringIO buffer has a wrong encoding, but I don't know how to make this work. If I do:

```
csv_buffer = StringIO.StringIO("")
```

I can create a readable CSV file, but then the zip part of the code fails:

```
    'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd4 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any explanation what's going wrong here would be appreciated!

**Edit:** Typo
**Edit 2 :** Added zip error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by explicitly defining the filename of the csv in the zip using the ZipInfo method like so:

```
zipinfo = zipfile.ZipInfo("{}.csv".format(i))
zipper.writestr(zipinfo, myfile.read())
```

And miraculously it worked! Might have to do with zipfile not supporting UTF filenames. But instead of throwing an error, it messes up the zipped file itself.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `StringIO`, use `BytesIO` as writestr of ZipFile will try to convert the second argument to bytes.

```
from io import BytesIO
zipped_file = BytesIO

with zipfile.ZipFile(zipped_file, 'w') as zipper:
    for i, myfile in enumerate(files):
        zipper.writestr("{}.csv".format(i), myfile.getvalue())

zipped_file.seek(0)
```

Also extra two cents from me is:

- don't use `file` as variable name. It's a python module.
- you can use `getvalue` so you don't have to reset `seek(0)` everytime

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if myfile = StringIO("") I get the error: StringIO instance has no attribute 'getValue'. If myfile = StringIO(), the zipping works, but the csv files are unreadable..